# How to sum values in typescript array based on array items property?

Tags: typescript, math

I'm working on small angular project. I have an array of receipt items, e.g. coke, fanta, pepsi, juice etc, with their prices and quantity of course.

```
receiptItems: Array<ReceiptItem>;
```

This is how `ReceiptItem` looks :

```
export class ReceiptItem {

  public id: string;
  public product: Product;
  public unitOfMeasure: UnitOfMeasure;
  public discount: number;
  public price: number;
  public quantity: number;
  public total: number;
  public tax:Tax;

 }
```

How can I in typescript get sum of total amount but only where property tax for example is equal to "25%"?

In C# I remember I've used lambda expressions like this:

```
IEnumerable<ReceiptItems> results = receiptItems.Where(s => s.Tax == "25.00");
   totalSum = results.Sum(x => (x.TotalAmount));
```

How to achieve something similar in TypeScript / Angular?

Answer (score 172, accepted):

Arrays in *JavaScript/TypeScript* also have these kind of methods. You can again `filter` with you condition and then use `reduce` aggregation function to sum the items.

```
const sum = receiptItems.filter(item => item.tax === '25.00')
                        .reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.total, 0);
```

`item.tax === '25.00'` - this part you must adjust with your logic

Comment: what does this line means? reduce((sum, current) => sum + current.total, 0);

Comment: `reduce` is an aggregation function like `Aggregate` in C#. It gets an total an every item in the iteration and in this case we sum each item's `total` to the `total` (sum) and finally get the sum

Comment: @Roxy'Pro: there's no direct JavaScript equivalent to `Sum()` LINQ function. But `Sum()` can be written using `Aggregate()`.

Comment: I like splitting operation like you do : `filter` then sum with `reduce`.

Comment: @roxypro: Notice that, as filter produces an intermediate array, in case `receiptItems` contains a lots of items, the filtering part can be done directly in the `reduce` : `receiptItems.reduce((sum, x) => sum + (x.tax === '25.00' ? x.total : 0));`