# aggregate array of objects based on certain properties typescript

Tags: arrays, typescript, dictionary

I have an array Order[], where Order is:

```
interface Order {
    orderId: number;        
    productName: string;
    color: string;
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
    link: string;
}
```

I want to create a mapping where:

- key is (productName, color)
- values are quantity, price, link. Quantity and price are a sum of matching properties of original objects. link is the same for all so can just keep one of them.

I know how to create a single item using filter and reduce, similar to this question: [How to sum values in typescript array based on array items property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52038271/how-to-sum-values-in-typescript-array-based-on-array-items-property)

I tried to use a Map object, but got stuck because I couldn't compare the keys properly - always got false

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more elegant way, but you could use a string template to represent the product/color combination.

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=64&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgPJQCbWQbwFDKHID2m0AkhgFzIgCuAtgEbQDcRHyBRADlMRjoIwAOTgMINAM5gooAOatuhBMQA2pabIVKOARzpxwwMAE8a9Zm2XI+wJBcYsouomtABrLXJCK8AXzw8UEhYRBQAZUYGOChTXBs+ASFRcUlkGR8-DlUNKG8dGwMjMBNzWidrDjsHCqsXAKDVEBlkGI8IAGkIeIBeZAAKUix8tDIoAEpkXoA+BI4oCDA6KBBkAAMAEhxh6AA6JMFhMQl-AH1t3ag93NJ-daVAvDMeFABBeXlF+ThIDHQRlJpvNkABtDrlTIKAC6NCiDBicUerjwzVaVykNAB0FB0OBoJs+E4RFuowAREw1HQIGSADQ2DjuEBeZBkgAWYDAPExAHoeVI4AA3EpqUx7EBLOkMohXSg0ACMACYAMz04mEGrpACcOrV6sOKRO6XZEDUGil6uQxWMZgVNn8esIRPVpJoZK+EAgIAt6qZLPZnO5VD5AuF4FF4sljs4suoyGVABYAKzR6pyWo6rWp3j8I6pCRutmm83ZwjW0q25Dy+3R53E12sj1en3Ev2FwO8-lCkViiVgFsx8Zy5AqhOl2zp7W66Ua3OGtKF4vEAf6Qw28rVjiBaFKVHEFpgZBfYh0IPID4en5-bFQIH9HD+JQYvYwUgAUUQbKG0zmdeQaMPCFgXaLoeiGCZXEIYAYAGABCY9TykcEemhKY-w4BDuWQ0w8X6YhIOQfxkFNKQUHQohMKQiFoQOSdkAAajw2j7AgAiMP4RDsJo8sygYkg9h4sx7QCCC8D5I8ONeDBkCYeIDWEZAjGk0k9xadQID2DR5AGSjRKAA)

```
interface Order {
    orderId: number;        
    productName: string;
    color: string;
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
    link: string;
}

interface Summary {
    productName: string;
    color: string;
    quantity: number;
    price: number;
}

const makeKey = (order: Order) => {
    return `${order.productName}_${order.color}`;
}

type AggregatedOrders = {
  [key: string]: Summary;
};
  
const orders: Order[] = [
    {
        color: "blue",
        link: "https://savantly.net",
        orderId: 123,
        price: 999,
        productName: "hello",
        quantity: 1
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        link: "https://savantly.net",
        orderId: 345,
        price: 999,
        productName: "hello",
        quantity: 1
    },
    {
        color: "green",
        link: "https://savantly.net",
        orderId: 234,
        price: 999,
        productName: "hello",
        quantity: 1
    }
];

const groups: AggregatedOrders = {};
orders.forEach(o => {
    const key = makeKey(o);
    if(!groups[key]) {
        groups[key] = o;
    } else {
        groups[key].price += o.price;
        groups[key].quantity + o.quantity
    }
});
// grouped by product and color
console.log(groups);
```